# AO Bake is not smooth

Tags: texture-baking

Although I have set the mesh to smooth and it does 'look' smooth, I get this when I bake:

[image]

Using BI and 30 samples normalized. I cant figure out what I've missed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is that the baked AO image?

Comment: Could you upload the concerned part of your model for test purpose? You can do it using this link: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/